# Using a variable value as a where statement inside PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Lets say I have the following variable:

```
$where = "where `hats`='red'";
```

I want to inject this variable into a PDO statement. What is the proper way of doing this?

Is it like so?:

```
$sql = "select * from `clothing` :where";
$stm = $this->app->db->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(':where', $where);
$stm->execute();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind *values*, not keywords, object names or syntactic elements. E.g., if you're always querying according to `hats`, you could bind the `'red'` value:

```
$color = 'red';
$sql = "select * from `clothing` where hats = :color";
$stm = $this->app->db->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(':color', $color);
$stm->execute();
```

If your `where` clause is really that dynamic, you'd have to resort to string manipulation (and face the risk of SQL injection, unfortunately):

```
$where = "where `hats`='red'";
$sql = "select * from `clothing` $where";
$stm = $this->app->db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
```

Comment: I upvoted to even you out. I agree, I'm building a dynamic where statement and I guess my only option is to inject it directly.

Answer (score -1):

// create a new PDO object by name $PDO in your connection file

In your function

```
  function nameOfFunction($var,$value)
   {
    global $PDO;
    $st=$PDO->prepare('SELECT * from clothing WHERE ? = ?');
    $rs=$st->execute(array($var,$val));
    return $st->fetchAll();
   }
```

I hope it will work. It will return the array, Traverse it as you like